# Tensorflow Real Time Significantly Greater Than CPU Time

Tags: c++, performance, tensorflow, benchmarking

So I have a model of `tensorflow` that is saved in a `protobuf` format. And I am trying to use this model for some real-time inference. It's performance critical so I test the inference latency by writing a simple google benchmark code.  But the read time is much greater than the CPU time from the result.
[image]
here is my env:

```
os:Ubuntu 18.04
tensorflow version:v 2.4.0, compiled from source, but same with distributed libtensorflow.so.
compiler: gcc 7.5.0
model: see screenshot below
```

[image]

Here is the snippet of the benchmarking code:

```cpp
constexpr static std::tuple<const char*, const char*, const char*>
MODELS[ 20 ]
{
    {"/home/echeng/tmp/tensorflow_trial/models/lstm_model_2023-10-05/",
     "serving_default_lstm_2_input",
     "StatefulPartitionedCall"
    },
    {"/home/echeng/tmp/tensorflow_models/v2.6.2/lstm_model_2023-10-31/",
     "serving_default_lstm_input:0",
     "StatefulPartitionedCall"
    }
};



const static cppflow::tensor t_tensor = cppflow::fill( {1, 1, 9}, 1.0f );
// cppflow::model model_1("/home/echeng/tmp/tensorflow_trial/models/lstm_model_2023-10-05/");
cppflow::model model_1(std::get<0>(MODELS[1]));

static void predict_timestamp_n( benchmark::State& in_state)
{
    std::size_t n_times = in_state.range(0);
    for ( auto _: in_state )
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i<n_times ; ++i)
        {
            auto output = model_1(
                // { { "serving_default_lstm_2_input", t_tensor } },
                { { std::get<1>(MODELS[1]), t_tensor } },
                { std::get<2>(MODELS[1]) }
            )[0];
        }
    }
}

BENCHMARK( predict_timestamp_n )
    ->Arg(1)
    ->Arg(10)
    ->Arg(100)
    ->Arg(1000)
;

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Is this a cache issue ? Or in principle can I get down to close to the CPU time ? because afaik neural network inference is mostly a CPU computatation-heavy task, so CPU time should be close to real time ?

Edit 1:
Some more information:

- I have created a dummy model that only consists of 44 params in total and reran the benchmark. It looks every number stays similar.
- Here is a glimpse of the `gperf` result:
  [image]

Edit 2:
I also test the inference of multiple timestamps at once. i.e. to pass in a tensor of the shape {1, 10, 9} for once rather than {1, 1, 9} for 10 times. The former goes down to very close to the CPU time in the benchmark.

Comment: CPU cache can't explain it; OS CPU scheduling isn't aware of cache misses since that doesn't free up the CPU to run other processes.  (And multiple cache misses can be in flight overlapping with useful work).  But hard page faults would suspend the timing; do you have enough RAM?  Check `vmstat 5` while its running and look for heavy swapping.

Comment: I also notice a high load average.  I assume that's just from previous benchmark runs, but if you have lots of other stuff running on this machine, it could be stealing CPU time from your benchmark.

Comment: Or is tensorflow using a GPU, and spending most of its time asleep waiting for the GPU to finish?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for replying! I checked `vmstat 5`. Only thing changed a log during the run is CPU cs & us. I can also ensure that it is not using GPUs. I have some more info that I have pasted in the original post.